# Matlab, hamiltonian system, plotting and energy calculation with Euler (backwards, forwards, mid point and semi-implicit)

Tags: matlab

This is the 2 body kepler problem.

The Hamiltonian is
[image: (p1^2)/2 + (p1^2)/2 - 1 / sqrt(q1^2+q2^2)]
[image: q1(0) = 1-a]
[image: q2(0) = 0]
[image: p1(0)=0]
[image: p2(0)=sqrt((1+a)/(1-a))]

[image: q1'' = -q1/(q1^2+q2^2)^(3/2)]
[image: q2'' = -q2/(q1^2+q2^2)^(3/2)]

This is supposed to be an "ellipse". How in the name of all that is holy can it be an ellipse when the initial values only have velocity components on one axis, and starting coordinates are on the same axis?

How do you plot the numerical solution using backwards euler?

Comment: Consider circular motion on a unit circle, i.e., an ellipse with equal axes. If my initial condition is `x0 = 0`, `y0 = 1`, and the motion is tangent to the circle, what can you tell me about the initial velocity vector?

Comment: Your "code" is not valid Matlab code. You should either post what you have tried and/or use LaTeX to format actual equations in order to make them readable.

Comment: I have LaTeX'd the equations, but note that StackOverflow lacks in-house LaTeX capabilities: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

I convert the two second-order equations into four first-order equations and solve using `ode23` (not backwards Euler, but a different numerical method).

```
odefun = @(t, y) [y(3);
                  y(4);
                  -y(1) / (y(1)^2 + y(2)^2)^(3/2);
                  -y(2) / (y(1)^2 + y(2)^2)^(3/2)]
p0 = [1 0];    % initial position
v0 = [0 1];    % initial velocity
[t y] = ode23(odefun, [0 20], [p0 v0])
comet(y(:,1), y(:,2))
```

You can see now that the path traced is an ellipse (actually a circle for my initial velocity). You can play with the inital conditions (`v0 = [0 1.1]` gives you an ellipse).

Comment: These equations are the exact opposite of [stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation) -there's no reason to use `ode23s`. Of Matlab's builtin explicit schemes, `ode23` or `ode45` are appropriate. If you don't like that these take large steps, resulting in jagged plots, use the `'Refine'` option with `odeset`. E.g.: `[t,y]=ode23(odefun,[0 20],[p0 v0],odeset('Refine',8));`. With `ode45` the relative tolerance needs to be increased to not loose energy due to numerical error (`ode45` defaults to `'Refine' = 4`): `[t,y]=ode45(odefun,[0 20],[p0 v0],odeset('RelTol',1e-5,'AbsTol',1e-5));`.

Comment: `ode45` didn't give a nice ellipse, but a slight spiral (due to the loss of energy you noted), so I changed it to `ode23s` arbitrarily as a second choice. I agree with what you've said, so I've changed my answer to use `ode23`

Comment: Thanks. The point is not that that `ode23s` works, it's that it is the wrong technique for this system. We don't want people new to numerical integration learning the wrong things. There's a very good reason for why `ode45` spirals in and loses energy: the system is so easy to integrate that the solver takes massive steps - only 33 to go from time 0 to time 20 and about three complete orbits (the true steps are obtained if `'Refine'` is 1). The solution to this problem is not to use a stiff solver that assumes that the system is hard to integrate, but to properly specify the tolerances.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i missunderstood what the system actually means, but what i see is a system with two bodies only under the influence of each others gravity. Starting position for body 1 is not a vector, but only a scalar, so it can only be located on the X axis. In this case it's coordinates are x = 1-a (0 < a < 1). Body 2 has it's starting position on x=0. Now, there is no force vectors pointing them away from the x axis, since the gravity gradient always is parallell to that same axis. The starting velocity is of course also a scalar, so there is no initial veolcity pointing them anywhere but on a parallell trajectory to the x axis.

When you say "this forms an ellipse", maybe i'm looking at the wrong coordinate system. I did the forward Euler plots as follows:

```
clear all, close all, clc

stl= 0.0005; % steplength
nos = 50000; % number of steps

q1 = zeros(1,nos);
q2 = zeros(1,nos);
q1v = zeros(1,nos);
q2v = zeros(1,nos);
q1a = zeros(1,nos);
q2a = zeros(1,nos);

% Starting positions
a=0.5;
q1(1) = 1-a;
q2(1) = 0;
q1v(1) = 0;
q2v(1) = sqrt((1+a)/(1-a));

% P is inertia, and has the same vector components as the body velocity

for i=1:nos-1    

[q1a(i),q2a(i)] = u1FUNC(q1(i),q2(i)); 

q1v(i+1) = q1v(i) + q1a(i).*stl; 
q2v(i+1) = q2v(i) + q2a(i).*stl;

q1(i+1) = q1(i) + q1v(i+1)*stl;
q2(i+1) = q2(i) + q2v(i+1)*stl;  

end

plot(q1)
hold on
plot(q2,'r')
```

u1FUNC

```
function [a,b] = func(c,d)

% [a,b] = [q1'',q2'']
% [c,d] = [q1,q2]

a = -c/(((c^2)+(d^2))^(3/2));
b = -d/(((c^2)+(d^2))^(3/2));

end
```

Now, this code gives a plot where q1 and q2 are plotted with q1 and q2 on the y axis and time on the x axis, which seems logical to me, if q1 and q2 decribes the distance for the body in question from the origo in a non-moving reference system. But how do you make it look like an ellipse?